# How to cluster strings by Hamming or Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, levenshtein-distance, hamming-distance

As an exercise, I would like to cluster a set of English words by Hamming or Levenshtein distance. If it is Hamming distance they will all have to be the same length (or padded to the same length) but this isn't true for the Levenshtein distance.

I normally use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/) which has a lot of clustering algorithms but none seem to accept arrays of categorical variables which is the most obvious way to represent a string.

I could precompute a massive distance matrix but this is unrealistic if the number of strings is at all large.

How can you cluster strings efficiently?

Comment: What size N is the set? This determines what size an NxN distance matrix would be, whether that would be massive or not, i.e. fit in memory.

Comment: @smci Around 100,000 strings.

Answer (score 1):

This seems relevant.

https://towardsdatascience.com/applying-machine-learning-to-classify-an-unsupervised-text-document-e7bb6265f52

This seems relevant too.

https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/

This example uses Affinity Propagation.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import distance
    
words = "kitten belly squooshy merley best eating google feedback face extension impressed map feedback google eating face extension climbing key".split(" ") #Replace this line
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:* %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))
    
    

# Result
 - *squooshy:* squooshy
 - *feedback:* feedback
 - *extension:* extension
 - *impressed:* impressed
 - *google:* google
 - *eating:* climbing, eating
 - *face:* face, map
 - *key:* belly, best, key, kitten, merley
```

Finally, I've been in the data science space for at least 8 years and I've heard of using Levenshtein Distance to compute cosine similarity, but I haven't see it used for clustering. Doing cosine similarity and clustering together, seems to make sense. Hopefully someone posts a solution here about that very thing.

Comment: The AffinityPropagation example makes a precomputed matrix which is only possible if the set of strings is small. The first link you gave seems to about document clustering. Are you suggesting I think of an individual string as a document made up of letters?  In this case we lose all ordering information for the letters in a string.

Comment: I interpreted it different, like each 'document' is a list of text strings. Maybe it's just ambiguous nomenclature, but I think all of the examples I shared illustrate the point of clustering strings of text.